# How to handle pagination in generating multiple page pdf in ios dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, pdf, ios6

I used the following code for generating pdf file and its contents.
Initially I designed the pdf content to draw table by drawing lines by giving cgpoint values to the lines.

```
+(void)drawPDF:(NSString*)fileName
{

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(fileName, CGRectZero, nil);

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 748), nil);


    int xOrigin = 50;
    int yOrigin = 300;

   int rowHeight = 120;
   int columnWidth = 130;

   int numberOfRows = 7;
    int numberOfColumns = 4;

    [self drawTableAt:CGPointMake(xOrigin, yOrigin) withRowHeight:rowHeight andColumnWidth:columnWidth andRowCount:numberOfRows andColumnCount:numberOfColumns];


   UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
}

 +(void)drawTableAt:(CGPoint)origin
  withRowHeight:(int)rowHeight
andColumnWidth:(int)columnWidth
   andRowCount:(int)numberOfRows
andColumnCount:(int)numberOfColumns

 {

    for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfRows; i++) {

        int newOrigin = origin.y + (rowHeight*i);


        CGPoint from = CGPointMake(origin.x, newOrigin);
        CGPoint to = CGPointMake(origin.x + (numberOfColumns*columnWidth), newOrigin);

        [self drawLineFromPoint:from toPoint:to];


    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {

        int newOrigin = origin.x + (columnWidth*i);


        CGPoint from = CGPointMake(newOrigin, origin.y);
        CGPoint to = CGPointMake(newOrigin, origin.y +(numberOfRows*rowHeight));

        [self drawLineFromPoint:from toPoint:to];


    }
}

+(void)drawLineFromPoint:(CGPoint)from toPoint:(CGPoint)to
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGFloat components[] = {0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3};

    CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(colorspace, components);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color);


    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, from.x, from.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, to.x, to.y);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
    CGColorRelease(color);

}
```

the output is as
[image]

but I specified numberOfRows to 7, only 3 rows were visible,view the remaining rows (ie,)  I need to view the second page of the pdf. 
numberOfRows may vary dynamically, if numberOfRows = 12 means the no. of pages in pdf should be 3 or above.
what to do?
I'm new to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you have to handle pagination yourself. Ie, with your call to

```
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 748), nil);
```

You only have one page here, 1024x768. You could certainly make that size larger too, but if you need to add a second page you'll have to add more. I think this link lays it all out for you:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html

(see that the first set of 6 steps shows you should repeat steps 2/3/4 as needed, where 2 is adding the page as you have).

Comment: how to repeat the second(creating a page) step.

Comment: Thanks, I did it by let the code  UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 748), nil); in for loop and did many customising frame settings for more pages and finally works fine.

Comment: Could you post the code you used that solved this? I have similar issue and would help to see how you did it.

Comment: Hi Nazik  can u explain me how u achieved this ...I need to view the second page of the pdf. numberOfRows may vary dynamically, if numberOfRows = 12 means the no. of pages in pdf should be 3 or above....

Comment: @NAZIK   hi can you send me your code of this for create pdf with multiple page .